# how to add test case directly under test suite of test manager using ITestCase

Tags: c#

As Itest case is interface we cannot create object of that.

I'm aware of work around by creating test case under project then add it to test manager.

Is there any option to directly create test case under test managers test plan-test suites?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
private static void CopyTestCaseIntoTestSuite(ITestCase sourceTestCase, IStaticTestSuite targetTestSuite)
{
    targetTestSuite.Entries.Add(sourceTestCase);
}
```

Tell me if you need additional help. :)